# Json and Java. From String to JSONObject: issues

Tags: java, json

I'm using the library `org.json`.

I have a string like this (quotes can't appear in `field_n`)

```
{field1=value1, field2=value2}  (say it `val`)
```

This string is obtained from an `Hashtable<String, Object>`.

I create a `JSONObject` from that string, obtaining:

```
{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"}
```

The issue arises when in the value `value_n` quotes (or newlines and carriage return) appear.

I've tried to escape the string in this way:

```
value = value.replace("\\", "\\\\");
value = value.replace("\"", "\\\"");
value = value.replace("\r", "\\r");
value = value.replace("\n", "\\n");
```

but I always obtain the `org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at ... [character ... line 1]` when I try to create the JSONObject with:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(val);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create JSON from map, use:

```
new JSONObject(myMap);
```

Another related issue:

```
quotedStr = JSONObject.quote(val.trim());
```

will qoute all needed values as it says:

> Produce a string in double quotes with backslash sequences in all the right places

Comment: I obtain the following exception `org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`.

Comment: @baraky - this will not work. It will just surround the entire JSON string with quotes, not the individual fields and values.

Comment: See if it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773663/jsonobject-text-must-begin-with

Comment: @baraky: nothing. Exception `org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at ... [character ... line 1]` is raised. The string is escaped (`{field1=dfds \"fdsfs\" fdfsd, field2=dsad\r\nfgfgfd}`), but the JSONObject construction fails at the first `\\`.

Comment: maybe you can use JSONObject.quote() on every object inside the JSON (what you get from the map) and just add "{" and "}" at the beginning and end.

Comment: And you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512692/listmapstring-object-to-org-json-jsonobject

Comment: Did you try JSONObject(myMap)?