# How to convert List<Map.Entry<String, String>> to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, java

I have a list in Java:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>>(map.entrySet());
```

My question is how to convert the above java list to Javascript array like this:

```
var prevYear = [["2011-08-01",398], ["2011-08-02",255.25], ["2011-08-03",263.9], ["2011-08-04",154.24]];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Or you are just expecting to give you the code ?

Comment: There are several libraries out there that convert Java objects to [JSON](http://json.org/). Take a look at the options, read up a bit about each one, and pick one you like. :)

Comment: You can use the solution from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10426838/2815219) answer. Once you have got the the return value from this function, you can use a simple `JSON.parse` in your javascript and pass the string that you received.

Comment: You start by converting the `Map.Entry<String, String>` into a `String[2]`, then ask a JSON library to format the `List<String[]>` as JSON.